# Como implementar uma paginação utilizando PHP e Ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

Faço uma consulta no banco de dados através do PHP que recebe os dados de um AJAX. (E depois retorna os dados da consulta para o AJAX)

Até ai tudo bem. O problema é que gostaria de realizar a paginação destes dados que retornam do AJAX. (São milhares de linhas)

**O meu maior problema é criar esses botões, da imagem abaixo, para a paginação (Essa é uma imagem de uma página feita com o DataTables):**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não vejo uma lógica correta de como fazer a criação e exibição desses botões de acordo com a quantidade de linhas retornadas do MySQL.

**Segue abaixo uma parte do meu código do AJAX, e do PHP.**

```js
function inserirFormulario(dados, select_de_filtro) {
  $("div#loading-resultado-pesquisa").html("<img src='../_imagens/load2.gif' width='300px'>");
  $("div#loading-resultado-pesquisa").show();
  $.ajax({
    //dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: dados.serialize(),
    url: "../banco/banco-vision/pagina-controle-de-tarefas/interface-resultado-pesquisa.php",
    cache: false,

  }).done(function(data) {
    var atividades = "";
    $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, valor) {
      //FUNÇÃO PARA FORMATAR AS DATAS QUE VEM DO PHP
      function dataAtualFormatada(parametro) {
        if (parametro == null) {
          parametro = "";
          return parametro;
        } else {
          var data = new Date(parametro),
            dia = data.getDate().toString(),
            diaF = (dia.length == 1) ? '0' + dia : dia,
            mes = (data.getMonth() + 1).toString(), //+1 pois no getMonth Janeiro começa com zero.
            mesF = (mes.length == 1) ? '0' + mes : mes,
            anoF = data.getFullYear();
          return diaF + "/" + mesF + "/" + anoF;
        }
      }

      var vencimento = dataAtualFormatada(valor.DT_VENCIMENTO);
      var inicio = dataAtualFormatada(valor.DT_INICIO);
      var fim = dataAtualFormatada(valor.DT_FIM);

      //CRIANDO AS LINHAS COM OS TD DA TABELA QUE SÃO O RESULTADO NA CONSULTA AO BANCO 
      atividades += '<tr class="' + valor.codigo + '" name="' + valor.STATUS + '">';
      atividades += '<td nowrap>' + valor.RESPONSAVEL + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td nowrap >' + valor.COD + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td nowrap>' + (valor.EMPRESAS.substring(0, 40)) + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td nowrap >' + valor.TRIBUTACAO + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td nowrap>' + (valor.TIPO_ATIVIDADE.substring(0, 50)) + '</td>';
      atividades += '<td ">' + vencimento + '</td>';

      if (valor.STATUS == "INICIADO") {
        atividades += '<td style="padding:0;text-align:left;" class="" ><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby justificar btn-info  css-botao-lista" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      } else if (valor.STATUS == "CONCLUIDO") {
        atividades += '<td  style="padding:0;text-align:left;"  class="" ><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby justificar btn-success  css-botao-lista" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      } else if (valor.STATUS == "CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO") {
        atividades += '<td style="padding:0;text-align:left;"  class="" ><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby justificar btn-dark  css-botao-lista" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      } else if (valor.STATUS == "VENCIDO") {
        atividades += '<td  style="padding:0;text-align:left;width:100%"  class="" ><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby justificar btn-danger  css-botao-lista" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      } else if (valor.STATUS == "PENDENTE") {
        atividades += '<td  style="padding:0;text-align:left;"  class="" ><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' reabriratividade  colocarstandby justificar btn-primary  css-botao-lista" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      } else if (valor.STATUS == "INICIADO_VENCIDO") {
        atividades += '<td  style="padding:0;text-align:left;"  class="" ><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + '  reabriratividade colocarstandby justificar btn-warning  css-botao-lista" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      }

      //botão stand_by do status
      else if (valor.STATUS == "STAND_BY") {
        atividades += '<td  style="padding:0;text-align:left;"  class="" ><button type="button" class="btn ' + valor.STATUS + ' justificar btn-secondary css-botao-lista" value="' + valor.codigo + '">' + valor.STATUS + '</button></td>';
      }

      //botão inserir detalhes
      atividades += '<td style="padding:0;text-align:center;" ><button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary botao-detalhes css-botao-list-no-width" <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-observacoes"><span class="text-light"><i class="fas fa-comment-dots"></i></span></a></button></td>';

      //botão reabrir atividade coluna
      atividades += '<td style="padding:0;text-align:center;" class=""><button  data-placement="botton" title="Voltar o Status da atividade para o estado anterior." type="button" class="btn btn-secondary reabrir-atividade-coluna css-botao-list-no-width" name="' + valor.STATUS + '" value="' + valor.codigo + '"><span><i class="fas fa-history"></i></span></button></td>';
      //botão stand by da coluna
      atividades += '<td style="padding:0;text-align:center;" class=""><button data-placement="bottom" title="Use esta opção caso a atividade não possa ser iniciada ou concluida, devido a algum fator externo como ausência de documentação necessária dentre outros, quando a atividade for concluida fora do prazo estando em STAND BY quando o funcionario clicar na atividade novamente, o funcionário não será prejudicado, a atividade será marcada como concluída." type="button" class="btn  btn-secondary stand-by-coluna css-botao-list-no-width" id="' + valor.codigo + '"  value="' + valor.COD + '"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i></button></td>';
      //Botão Remover linha 
      atividades += '<td style="padding:0;text-align:center;"  class=""><button  data-placement="top" title="Clique aqui para remover esta atividade, esta ação não apagará as atividades anteriores nem as futuras." type="button" class="btn btn-secondary botao-remover css-botao-list-no-width"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>';



      //Botão Justificar
      atividades += '<td style="padding:0;text-align:center;" class=" css-botao-list-no-width"><button  data-placement="top" title="A ferramenta de justificar deve ser usada, quando por algum problema alheio ao funcionário a atividade foi concluída fora do prazo de vencimento, ela será marcada como JUSTIFICADO e STATUS CONCLUIDO, não gerando prejuizo ao funcionário." type="button" class="btn btn-success botao-justificar css-botao-list-no-width"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></button></td>';


      atividades += '<td style="padding:0;text-align:center;" class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody td-padding"><button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Clique aqui para ver o arquivo" class="btn  btn-secondary css-ver-arquivo botao-ver-arquivo ' + valor.codigo + '"  value="' + valor.COD + '"><a class="text-light" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-lista-arquivos-atividade" style="text-decoration:none"><span><i class="far fa-eye"></i></span></a></button></td>';


      atividades += '</tr>';


    });

    $('#registros-atividades').html(atividades);



    $("div#loading-resultado-pesquisa").hide();

  }).fail(function() {

  }).always(function() {

  });
}
```

```html
<?php 


$pesquisar    = "SELECT COD, RESPONSAVEL, EMPRESAS, TRIBUTACAO, TIPO_ATIVIDADE, STATUS, DETALHES, FEEDBACK, DT_VENCIMENTO, DT_INICIO, DT_FIM, codigo, possui_arquivo FROM tbl_atividades";
   $pesquisar    .= " WHERE COD like '%$cod' AND EMPRESAS like '%$empresas' AND EMPRESA_ORIGEM like '%$user_empresa_origem_click_dashboard%' AND TRIBUTACAO like '%$tributacao' AND TIPO_ATIVIDADE like '%$atividade' AND departamento like '%$departamento_click_dashboard%' AND STATUS = 'STAND_BY' $variavel LIMIT $limit";
 
   
   $operacao_consulta = mysqli_query($conecta, $pesquisar) or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados"); 
   
     
   $retorno = array();
   while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($operacao_consulta))
   {    
     
    $retorno[] = $linha;
      
   }  
   
   
   echo json_encode($retorno); 
   
  break;
  
   
 }  
   
  
?>
```

**Segue abaixo uma imagem de como o sistema está agora.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Já procurei em diversos sites e fórum e não consegui algo claro. Talvez por eu nunca ter feito algo do tipo (com paginação). Encontro muito conteúdo, porém com php puro.**

Desde já agradeço a atenção. Obrigado!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pense da seguinte maneira:

1. Navegação entre as páginas:

   - O total de páginas é o total de registros dividido pela quantidade por 
     página, por exemplo: 1000 registros, 100 registros por página = 10 páginas
   - É necessário [uma consulta para pegar o total de registros](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_count.asp) além da consulta 
     de cada página
2. Relação entre o número da página e o limit

   - Cada página representa [uma porção do total dos registros](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php), por exemplo:

     - Página 1: do registro 0, até o registro 100
     - Página 2: do registro 100, até o registro 200
     - Página 3: do registro 200, até o registro 300

Uma implementação seguindo esta lógica:

```
<?php

$registrosPorPagina = 100;
$totalDeRegistros = 1000;
$totalDePaginas = $totalDeRegistros / $registrosPorPagina;

$paginaAtual = 5;
$rangeMin = ($paginaAtual - 1) * $registrosPorPagina;
$rangeMax = $paginaAtual * $registrosPorPagina;

//sql: SELECT * FROM tabela LIMIT $rangeMin,$rangeMax
```

Implemente esta lógica, e envie o número da página solicitada pelo ajax, e será retornado a porção correspondente à página.

Comment: Beleza, entendi. Muito bom. Mas eu já tinha visto algo parecido com essa lógica sua em alguns fóruns. Porém, minha dificuldade é que eu tenho um código pronto de consulta, como mostrei no exemplo postado na pergunta. Como eu, com base na minha consulta, mandaria para o AJAX um retorno dessa sua lógica ? E a dúvida principal, como eu criaria os botões da forma que eu mostrei no exemplo ? Digo: Anterior 12345...1000 Próximo. Essa é minha real dúvida. Desculpe se não fui muito claro.

Comment: E como faria a lógica de mandar para o php o ponto no qual eu desejo realizar o select ? Exemplo: Se eu apertar o botão '3' (Se for pra mostrar de 10 em 10 registros) ele só mostrar do mostraria os registros da linha 21 à 30.

Comment: Seria a questão na verdade de dizer qual é a página atual (Que presumo ser mandada quando clicamos no botão numérico).

Comment: Como eu criaria esses botões enumerados com os números das páginas ?

Comment: Essa lógica ajudou bastante, brother. Só tive que adaptar bastante para atender a minha necessidade. Obrigado !